# Can we recreate pdb$seed in Oracle database 19c

Tags: oracle, multi-tenant, database-administration, oracle19c

I have lost by mistake the pdb$seed from my multitenant architecture of database.
Is there some possible way to recreate the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a regular PDB that was created from the seed database, you can close this regular PDB into a new seed database.

If you have already made changes to the regular PDB, the easiest is to create a (temporary) new CDB (which comes with a fresh seed database) using the Database Creation Assistant and clone the seed database from the temporary CDB to your CDB. After that, drop the temporary CDB.